# Display input element when select option

Tags: html, select

I have a select element in the form with different options. On property of the 'select' is `onchange="testRecurrence(this.form)"` and the js function it's just:

```
function testRecurrence(form) {
    if(form.repeat.value != "N") {
        form.endR.style.display = 'inline';
    }

    return true;
}
```

Being 'repeat' the select and 'endR' the item I want to display in case the option value is not "N". The issue here is that this is not working... been trying to find a solution but not able. Any help?

**update**
Not working, the element stay always hidden. The element endR by default has `display:none`.

**update2**
js function changed to:

```
function testRecurrence(form) {
    if(form.repeat.options[form.repeat.selectedIndex].value != 'N')
        document.getElementById('endR').style.display = 'inline';        
}
```

html:

```
<select name="repeat" onchange="testRecurrence(this.form)">
...
<div id="endR" style="display: none">
...
</div>
```

It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Define "not working". What happns or doesn't happen? Does the element always stay invisible, or always visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think getting the value of a select element doesn't work on all browsers, but this should do:

```
form.repeat.options[form.repeat.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: This way I get the value of 'repeat' correctly and works fine on the 'if' condition but the <div name="endR"> is not visible still.

Comment: you can only get form elements by form.elementName; a div is a regular element so the name attribute is not valid. You should use the id attribute, and access it by document.getElementById('divId').